# If statements: Something Wrong with my logic

Tags: python

I'm in CS 1 and am learning python. We just finished learning if statements and boolean data types. I have to write a program that reads the temperature value and C for Celsius or F for Fahrenheit and then print whether the inputed number is a solid liquid or a gas. Here is my code but I cant seem to get it to work quite right

```
temp = input("Temp in C or F(like 5C or 5F): ")
this = ("-")
Faren = ("F")

if temp.find ("C") :
    if this in temp:
       len(temp)
       newTemp = temp[0] + temp[1]
       newTempOne = int(newTemp)
       tempOne =((newTempOne * 9) / 5 + 32)
    else:
        len(temp)
        newTemp = temp[0]
        newTempOne = int(newTemp)
        tempOne =((newTempOne * 9) / 5 + 32)
    if tempOne >= 212:
        print("gaseous")
    elif tempOne <= 32 or tempOne == tempOne * -1 :
        print("solid")
    elif 212 > tempOne > 32:
        print("liquid")
else:
    if faren in temp :
        if this in temp:
            len(temp)
            tempNum = temp[0] + temp[1]
            newTempNum = int(tempNum)
    else:
        if faren in temp :
            len(temp)
            tempNum = temp[1]
            newTempNum = int(tempNum)
        if newTempNum  >= 212:
            print("gaseous")
        elif newTempNum > 32:
            print("solid")
        elif newTempNum == newTempNum * -1:
            print("solid")
        elif 212 > newTempNum > 32 :
            print("liquid")
```

Comment: One of your problems is flawed logic.  For example, how can `elif newTempNum == newTempNum * -1:` ever be `True`?  Unless `newTempNum` is 0, but then you could just do `elif newTempNum == 0:` or even just `elif not newTempNum:`.

Comment: The first question is: what's wrong with it? Does it raise an exception for certain inputs? Print out the wrong answer? If so, give us the inputs, the expected and wrong outputs, and (if relevant) the exception with traceback.

Comment: `elif newTempNum > 32:` I guess this should be 
`elif newTempNum < 32:`

Comment: Also, you might want to add some `print`s throughout to print out the intermediate values and figure out where it first goes wrong.

Comment: Some more problems: You've got `if faren in temp:`, then `else:` with `if faren in temp:` inside of it. There's no way that inner `if` could possibly ever be true—the `else` already says it's not true. Meanwhile, the `temp[0] + temp[1]` you do all over the place` just gives you the first two characters. So, for example, in the case of `-158C`, it's going to be `-1`, which isn't very useful. For similar reasons, you'll read `60C` as `6`, which will give you the wrong answer.

Comment: The errors begin with using `input` to read a string (I presume), which it does, but then it also executes it as Python code. Also, `if temp.find ("C")` will only ever be false if the character C is _found at the start of the string._

Comment: @AndreasBombe: No, this is clearly Python 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole series of bugs, and you need to fix all of them to make this work. Let's go through them one by one. [Here](http://pastebin.com/5LQXvHBh) is the final result of fixing them all (and changing as little else as possible).

---

The first thing you need to fix is all the places where you convert the string into a number. You're using `temp[0] + temp[1]` for negative numbers, and `temp[0]` otherwise. That means that, for `-123C` or `451F` you'll just get `-1` or `4`.

If you're looking to strip off the `C` or `F` at the end, use slicing for that: `temp[:-1]`. Or, alternatively, `temp.rstrip('CF')` to make it explicit.

That's your only bug with Celsius temperatures. There are a lot of things you could clean up, but none of them actually cause an error.

---

But Fahrenheit temperatures have a few new more problems.

First, `temp.find("C")` will return `-1` if it's not found. And -1 is a true value. All numbers other than `0` are true values. What you want here is `if "C" in temp`—the same thing you use have all over the place.

---

Once you do that, you'll get an exception, because you check for `faren`, but you never defined anything with that name; you defined `Faren`, but that isn't the same thing. Capitalization counts. So, change one or the other so they match.

---

Now, nothing will print out for Fahrenheit temperatures, because all of the printing code happens inside the `else`. You need to unindent those last 8 lines so they happen after the `if`/`else`, whichever way the `if`/`else` goes.

---

Next, you don't have any case that will ever print `solid`, except 0. `newTempNum == newTempNum * -1` is only true if it's 0. And 212 > newTempNum > 32 is only true if it's > 32, in which case it would already have been caught by the earlier case. You got the logic right for Celsius, so just use the same logic again here.

And now it works for negative Fahrenheit numbers.

---

For positive Fahrenheit numbers, you still get a `NameError` exception for `newTempNum`. Why? Well, `if faren in temp`, you have an `if this in temp`, but no `else`. So, negative numbers do the right thing and assign `newTempNum` to the right value, but positive numbers do nothing at all, which means they assign it no value, which means you get an error when you look for that value.

Really, you don't need the `if this in temp` at all—the exact same code will work for both positive and negative numbers. So, just remove it.

And now it works for both Celsius and Fahrenheit, positive and negative.

---

But if you give it a string with neither letter in it, you'll get a `NameError` again. That's because, inside the `else` that goes with `if faren in temp`, you've got an `if faren in temp`. The `else` only happens if faren *isn't* in temp, so this `if` can never happen. I'm not sure what you wanted to do here anyway. Maybe `print("Sorry, that has neither a C nor an F, so I don't know what to do with it")`. You'll still get an error *after* printing that, but at least it'll make it obvious that the user is at fault, not your code.

And now it does the right thing for every valid input, and it quits with an error for every invalid input. If you want to clean it up and simplify it, add better error handling or input validation, etc., you can, but the basics are done.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few logic errors in your code.  For instance when you are trying to strip the F or C off your input so you can convert it to an int.  If the input was 10F or 100F or a 1000F, you will always get "1" when you do this: `newTemp = temp[0]`   One way to do what you mean is `newTemp = temp[:-1]`.  This is taking the stuff in temp, starting with the character at index 0 (the 0 is implied before the :) and ending at the next to last character.  You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)

If your input does have an F in it, it looks like it would never get to the code that will print the matters state.  The part that prints the state if is under the else of the if that tests for the F.

If I were you I'd start fresh and first think it out in pseudo code.  Here is how I'd do it:

```
Get input
Check for an F with an if statement.
If it has an F, strip the F and convert the number to an int and store for later use.
Check for a C with an if statement.
If it has a C, strip the C and convert the number to an int and store.
Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and store the answer.
Do the tests to check what state  and print appropriate state.
```